# How to write a pandas dataframe to kdb+ partition table on disk

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, kdb

I need to use kdb+ in Python, so tried [qpython](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) 2.0 to write a Pandas dataframe like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym':['abc','def','ghi'],'price':[10.1,10.2,10.3]})
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    q.sendSync('{t::x}',df)
```

and query:

```py
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    df1 = q.sendSync('select from t')
```

It looks working, but the table is saved in memory. How to write the Pandas dataframe directly into a partitioned table on disk?

Answer (score 0):

This thread covers a similar question:

- https://community.kx.com/t5/kdb-and-q/Csv-file-to-partitioned-table/m-p/1009

You could adapt the code from this article:

- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/loading-from-large-files/

Specifically this file:

- https://github.com/KxSystems/cookbook/blob/master/dataloader/loader.q

Other links:

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#dpft-save-table
- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/partition/